# Google Pubsub: messages fall into unacked and stuck there for a few minutes

Tags: c#, .net, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a pubsub subscription with the following params:

- Delivery type: Pull
- Acknowledgement deadline: 15 seconds
- Retry policy: Retry immediately

etc, full on the screen.

Also I have a message handler with the following logic:

```
Func<Subscription, PubsubMessage, CancellationToken, Task<SubscriberClient.Reply>> gcpHandler = (subscription, msg, ctInner) =>
        {
           _logger.LogInformation($"Got some message!");
           
           // I call this async job without await to complete message 
           // handler work immediately and consume the next messages asap
           vat backgroundTask = SomeAsyncBackgroundJob(msg) 

           _logger.LogInformation($"Message was successfully processed!");
           return Task.FromResult(SubscriberClient.Reply.Ack);
        }

var subscriberTask = subscriber.StartAsync((msg, _) => gcpHandler(subscription, msg, ct));
```

So, code inside the gcpHandler is very fast. The execution is about 1-5 ms. For me it's ok to do all work in the background task to let consumer ack all messages immediately.

In common it works fine BUT sometimes something happens and my gcpHandler doesn't receive any messages for a few minutes.

I mean, I send for example 6 messages but I don't even see "Got some message!" log for any of them. At this moment I can see on graphics that these messages were unacked (but how? my consumer hadn't even got any of them yet!). After ~4 min my consumer finally gets these messages and processes them without any problems.
This issue happens randomly and I have no idea why does it happen.

There is no any error, exception or something

I have Retry immediately policy so message must be processed immediately anyway but it stuck for ~4 min

Does someone had something like that? What should I check in this case?
I've attached graphics at these moment

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is the message order feature required? it could be that which force PubSub to calculate again the right order and than to resume the delivery. It's not sure, and it's not a smooth behavior, but it could be the reason

Comment: Is the message order really could be the reason of 4min delay only for 6(!) messages in subscription at this moment?
And the issue happens randomly. I mean it works ok most of the time. But I will try to test it without message ordering anyway, thx

Comment: Hi @Alex k, Could you please confirm if disabling the `message ordering` help you resolving the issue or not ?

Comment: @DhirajSingh I've been testing today and haven't reproduced the issue after disabling the message ordering. But the problem occurred randomly so I continue watch the problem at least for now. If all be ok I will write an answer about messaging ordering impact

Comment: Using message ordering shouldn't inherently result in such latency for delivering messages. You may need to reach out to support so they can look at your topic and subscription specifically to understand what resulted in delayed delivery.

Comment: Hi @Alex, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP [support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/). Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) describing your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's weird but looks like the reason of such delay was enabled the **message ordering** (thanks to tips in comment section)

The case is we had some topics (30-50 items) and subscriptions (200-300 items). Message ordering was enabled for each of them. **The ordering key was the same for all subscriptions**, i.e. kind of global value. And probably that's the reason of some delay. I've disabled this feature and haven't seen this issue the whole week. The only thing I haven't understood is why the issue was happened randomly...

Anyway, if you will encounter similar delay - try to disable message ordering first